# How to implement fade in effect for CSS checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating some sort of slide show using `CSS radio input`. So I have some buttons that pressing each will show some `div`s. I like have some animation in that so data `fadein` from left.

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
    var $panel = $(el);
    var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
    var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

    $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
        var $input = $(elInput);
        var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

        $input.attr('id', inputId);
        $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
    });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}

.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to add the fade effect. I don't mind CSS or jQuery but CSS animation wont work with `display: none`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a CSS `animation` when the `radio input` state is `:checked`.

```
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slideToRight 300ms linear forwards;
}
@keyframes slideToRight {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

---

### CODE SNIPPET:

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
  var $panel = $(el);
  var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
  var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

  $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
    var $input = $(elInput);
    var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

    $input.attr('id', inputId);
    $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
  });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slideToRight 300ms linear forwards;
}
@keyframes slideToRight {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can always set an `animation-delay` between slides. If your component will have more than 3 slides you should consider using javascript to set these delays.

### CODE SNIPPET:

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
  var $panel = $(el);
  var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
  var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

  $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
    var $input = $(elInput);
    var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

    $input.attr('id', inputId);
    $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
  });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slideToRight 300ms linear forwards;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}
@keyframes slideToRight {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

To prevent the `animation` from running on page load, it will be added after the user clicks any radio `input`.

```
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}

.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .playing {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slideToRight 300ms linear forwards;
}
```

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").addClass("playing");
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
  var $panel = $(el);
  var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
  var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

  $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
    var $input = $(elInput);
    var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

    $input.attr('id', inputId);
    $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
  });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .playing {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: slideToRight 300ms linear forwards;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.panelTop > div input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}
@keyframes slideToRight {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. it works great. Only one question. Currently the animation starts working with as soon as the page is running or when you press the run button in your sample. Is it possible to make it animated only when one of the items is pressed and not  with the page load? I think it works with the page load since one item is checked by default.

Comment: Sure you can! You would need to use another class though, and then add it with javascript. I will edit my answer to provide a code snippet.